# Visual Studio 2010 Javascript/jQuery Documentation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, documentation

OKay, TWO questions here:

1. Is there anything like GhostDoc for JS?
2. Are there any good help file generators that can use both C# *AND* JS source files to generate documentation? It looks like SandCastle doesn't support a web site as opposed to a web project with .proj files. And, as far as I can tell, Natural Docs doesn't support the Visual Studio style documentation... so that won't work.

I feel like I'm missing something here. I just can't believe that people out there are commenting their JS by hand... there HAS to be something, right?

I've searched high and low. I'm asking as a last resort. Please just tell me that I stink at searching and that there are easy solutions to this! :-)

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of commenting that you want the system to provide? Do you strictly mean the `///<summary>` block above a function (and related JavaDocs)? Or is there something else you're looking for this documentation engine to do?

Comment: Just the standard, intellisense supported style...

Comment: Sorry, example:
----
(function ($) {
    $.fn.helpfulTips = function (options) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Helpful Tips
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options">options</param>
    /// <returns>jQuery</returns>
    var defaults = {
        pointer: "#theArrow"
    };
...
---

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Why are you using a Website instead of a Web Project? Web Projects are easier to deploy, easier to test, easier to tie external source into, and easier to pick and choose what you should and should NOT be deploying.

Answer (score 1):

You gave this as an example (would've been nice to put it in the question proper, maybe a mod will come by and do that for you, since you should be able to edit your own questions) and you want to know if the `/// <summary>` block can be automatically inserted in the javascript part of the code, not just in the .cs files.

```
(function ($) { $.fn.helpfulTips = function (options) { 
    /// <summary>  
    /// Helpful Tips 
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="options">options</param>  
    /// <returns>jQuery</returns>  
    var defaults = { pointer: "#theArrow" };
    } 
});
```

I should think it would, but I just type that stuff so fast that I don't realize I'm typing it. I tend to do mine manually too, but I don't generally have a need to javadoc my code (we don't use javadocs), so I don't know if there are any automated tools to help with that in VS. I was curious so I'm hanging onto this post (favorited) so I can see if anyone else has good thoughts on this.

Comment: Thanks for formatting it properly.
I also looked into Doxygen, but that doesn't support anything but super basic JS. 
How am I the ONLY one that wants both INTELLISENSE and DOCUMENTATION for JS? I swear I must be missing something...

Comment: So ... you are aware that if you javadoc your javascript and name it in just such a way that VS will use the intellisense from the file to assist you, right?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Right... but now what can I use for a help file generator? I've looked at Doxygen, Natural Docs, etc...

Comment: ooooooh /facepalm ... um, the regular javadoc generators don't work? hmmm

Comment: Not for JS... they don't support the visual studio style documentation like I have in my example. Thanks for all your help, btw, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Are "javadoc" and the xml documentation style that VS uses the same thing?

Comment: I've always heard them referred to as the same thing ... however a quick glance at wikipedia tells me I'm wrong ... doh!

Comment: Any ideas on how to generate the help file?

Comment: Have you looked at SandCastle?

Comment: Yup. The AjaxDoc plugin stinks... do you know of any other plugins for it that support JS?

Comment: Sadly, no I don't. Sandcastle is as advanced as I know. We just don't have a need for javadoc or xmlcomments so we don't screw with them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087656/c-documentation-from-source

Comment: Crummy. Oh well. Guess I'll have to roll my own :-)  Thanks again for all your help. I appreciate all the replies. You made me feel like I'm not crazy!

Answer (score 1):

You must reference all the js files will be used in the source by adding:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
/// <reference path="facebox.js" />
```

top of your javascript file. This way, you can get intellisense in javascript.

One last thing, some js frameworks (eg. jQuery) have a -vsdoc.js file for intellisense. You must place that files where your original js files resides in; and names of them must be match.

if your js files name is "test.js" then your -vsdoc file must be named: "test-vsdoc.js"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YuiDoc](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/) to generate a JavaDoc like output.  I've used it and was very please with the output it provides.  You need to use their format for comments which is not the same as the Visual Studio format.

Comment: Have you used YuiDoc in a Visual Studio project?  Were you able to find a DLL or did you just install Python in order to run it?

Comment: I installed python and the required libraries YuiDoc needs.  You should be able to create a MsBuild task to run YuiDoc automatically when you build or use External Tools Screen under the Tools menu in Visual Studio to setup a way to easily run the tool from within Visual Studio.  One thing I should warn you about YuiDoc is that if you plan on creating your structure then you will probably run into problems. I know because I did.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything on this list of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221413/what-tools-are-available-for-documenting-javascript ?